# Ensuring code is executed *after* a change to a watched property has taken effect in the UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, how can I ensure code is only executed *after* a change to a watched property has taken full effect in the UI.

For example, say that the visiblity of a loading indicator is bound to the the value of a `isLoading` property on a model. How can I ensure that subsequent functionality is only executed after the loading indicator has become visible?

e.g.

**my-template.html**

```
<my-loading-indicator ng-show="model.isLoading"></my-loading-indicator>
```

**my-controller.js**

```
// ...
MyController.prototype.doSomething = function() {
  this.model.isLoading = true;
  // how can I guarantee that the UI is now showing the loading indicator before proceeding?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use `$timeout` which will not be run until digest cycle completes.

```
// will start digest cycle since it is bound to `ng-show`
this.model.isLoading = true;

$timeout(function(){
   // indicator should be visible now
}[,optional delay]);
```

Don't forget to inject `$timeout` wherever you are using it

Comment: OK thanks. Why will `this.model.isLoading` trigger a digest. It is a model update occurring outside of AngularJS is it not?

Comment: seems reasonable to me

Comment: Further to my previous comment, surely a scope.$digest call is needed to ensure a digest occurs due to the model update occurring directly and without AngularJS' knowledge?

Comment: gets called internally by `$timeout`. Similar to `ng-` event handling directives or `$http` callbacks ... angular does it under the hood

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$scope.$apply();` for triggering a $digest.

*"When a $digest cycle runs, the watchers are executed to see if the scope models have changed. If they have, then the corresponding listener functions are called."*

Comment: If you step through code similar to that in my `doSomething` method in the question, it is demonstrably **not** the case that the loading indicator is made visible before any further logic is invoked, so while your answer is factually correct, it does not address my question AFAICT.

Comment: You are right! Now I understand your question, $timeout is an Angular's wrapper for window.setTimeoutset. Timeout removes the function from the execution queue and it will only be invoked after JavaScript has finished with the current execution queue. So that is way your model will be updated before the excecution.